# How to Transfer a value from an inline function parameter to a global variable

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, electron

I'm using Electron with Ionic 5, I currently have a problem on how to transfer the passed value from the renderer to a global variable.

What i want to do is that, once i close one of my browser window on electron, it will automatically inform my homepage.ts about that. It actually work (if only doing console log of the result inside the function like closing the other browser window, it outputs the **close** returned value asynchronously), however doing so to a global variable in my homepage.ts doesn't work.

I have this function from my homepage.ts

```
async initialize() {
if (this.electron.isElectronApp) {
  var x;
        this.electron.ipcRenderer.on("action-prio-external-queue", (err,arg) => {
          if(arg == 'close') {
            x = false;
            console.log(arg);
          }           
        })
        console.log(await x);
  }
}
```

electron.ts

**win** is the variable name of my electron browser window.

```
win.webContents.send('action-prio-external-queue', 'close');
```

as i've said, doing console.log(arg) shows correct output, however transferring it to a global variable doesn't work.

Are you able to advice? if so That would be great! thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var arg;
async initialize() {
if (this.electron.isElectronApp) {
  var x;
        this.electron.ipcRenderer.on("action-prio-external-queue", (err,a) => {
          if(arg == 'close') {
            x = false;
            arg = a;
          }           
        })
        console.log(await x);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i was able to confirm that my code is working. However now i pinpoint the problem which is about the async or something on my html, the boolean variable i used on my page html is not updating, while the boolean variable is correct when printed on a console.log. can you advise?